# How can I add a "Load more" button to show more comments in my django project template with jquery or ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

In my django template I don't want to list all comments. If a user clicks the show more button I want to load some more comments.

I researched much but I have no jquery, ajax or javascript knowledge. So I didn't find anything usefull. Is there anyone who can help me?

profile.html

```
<div class="widget review-listing">
  <ul class="comments-list" id="loadmorecomment">
    {% if comments %}
      {% for comment in comments %}
        <li>
          <div class="comment">
            <img class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle" alt="User Image" src="{{comment.comment_user.image.url}}">
            <div class="comment-body">
              <div class="meta-data">
                <span style="white-space:pre" class="comment-author">{{comment.comment_user.unvan}} {{comment.comment_user.get_full_name}}</span>
                <span class="comment-date">{{ comment.updated_date|timesince }}</span>
                <div class="review-count rating">
                  {% if comment.star != 0 %}
                    {% for i in comment.star|rjust:comment.star %}  
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled"></i>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if comment.none_star != 0 %}
                  {% for i in comment.none_star|rjust:comment.none_star %}    
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                  {% endfor %} 
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
              <p  class="comment-content">
                {{comment.comment}}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <p style="color: orange;">No comment</p>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
    
  <!-- Show All -->
  <div class="all-feedback text-center">
    <a id="#loadMore" name="more_comments" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
      Load more comments <strong>({{comments.count}})</strong>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- /Show All -->
</div>
```

Comment: I think you'll find this helpful: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html

Comment: It is good documentation,thanks.I tried it,but every time ı click button page is reloading.I want when i press the load more comment button,comments will load without refreshing page

Comment: Ahh, okay. My bad. In that case, I believe this is closer to what you're looking for? https://alphacoder.xyz/lazy-loading-with-django-and-jquery/